# leaflet polylines and bringtofront on overlapping lines

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have:

```
var lines = volLines[name];
```

where name is the name for a group of polylines, each 'lines' has a marker with "name" displayed where i do this:

```
.addTo(mymap).on('click', changeMapLineColour);
```

When I click on a marker that is associated for the group of polylines the lines all change colour. The problem I have is there are many other groups of polylines so sometimes the lines that I have change the colour of are under other groups of polylines so I cannot see all the lines. How do I bring the lines associated with "name" to the front when the lines overlap?

```
function changeMapLineColour()
{ //other stuff in here, just given basics for this problem.
   lines[i].setStyle({
                            color: "white",
                            weight: 4
                        }) 
}
```

I found this but I am unsure of how to use it and where to put in cshtml?

```
actions: {
  bringToFront(e) {
    e.target.bringToFront();
  }
}
{{polyline-layer ... onAdd=(action "bringToFront")}}
```

Or is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a layer (from an array of lines) like this to then be able to bringToFront()

```
var layer = lines[i].setStyle({
                    color: "white",
                    weight: 4
                })
                layer.bringToFront();
```

woohoo!